# Twisted SMTP server, adding SSL support, 2 factories?

Tags: ssl, smtp, twisted, factory

Having recently asked [Twisted mail server with TLS - no portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338633/twisted-mail-server-with-tls-no-portal)  It seems I was barking up the wrong tree - so now it seems pertinent and appropriate to ask a fresh, revised question.

So I am trying to extend the basic SMTP server sample found at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac to support SSL connections. I can create an ssl Context Factory as follows (code lifted from my previous efforts:

```
caCertFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/CA/cacert.pem","r")
certFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/server/server.crt","r")
keyFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/server/server.key","r")
caCertData = caCertFile.read()
pKeyData = keyFile.read()
certData = certFile.read()
caCert = ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(caCertData)
cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, certData)
pKey = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, pKeyData)
sslCtxFactory = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=pKey, certificate=cert, trustRoot=caCert)
```

So now I have the SMTP Factory from emailserver.tac, and my sslCtxFactory above. In my old code, I created an object of class ESMTP as follows:

```
myESMTP = ESMTP(contextFactory=sslCtxFactory)
factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(lambda: mySMTP(contextFactory=sslCtxFactory))
endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8001)
endpoint.listen(factory)
```

But since this code isn't using a portal etc, then some of the methods/functions in the class definition for ESMTP fail owing to various attributes not being defined (eg self.delivery, self.portal).

So I'm trying to understand how to implement my sslCtxFactory in the mailserver.tac code - while still using a portal / realm as per mailserver.tac, so as to ensure the methods in twisted's ESMTP class don't fail.

But how can I bring these two factories "together"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks strange:

> ```
> myESMTP = ESMTP(contextFactory=sslCtxFactory)
> factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(lambda: mySMTP(contextFactory=sslCtxFactory))
> ```

Instances of the `ESMTP` class provided by Twisted aren't callable.  I think you must have meant something like:

```
from functools import partial

myESMTP = partial(ESMTP, contextFactory=sslCtxFactory)
factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(mySMTP)
```

Assuming so...

The `ESMTP` class respects the `self.portal` attribute for its authentication and authorization behavior.  All you need to do is get it set.

`SMTPFactory` is a factory for `SMTP` instances that sets the protocol's `portal` attribute to the value of its own (the factory's) `portal` attribute.  The only trouble is that it makes `SMTP` instances instead of `ESMTP` instances.

Fortunately, it (the factory) respects its `protocol` attribute for the class to instantiate.

If you were to write:

```
portal = Portal(...)
myESMTP = partial(ESMTP, contextFactory=...)
factory = SMTPFactory.forProtocol(protocol=myESMTP, portal=portal)
```

then you would have a factory which:

- creates instances of ESMTP
- passes `contextFactory=...` to the initializer of `ESMTP` when instantiating it
- sets the `portal` attribute on the `ESMTP` instances after it instantiates them, using the value passed in to `forProtocol` here.